# Google Calendar API Events.list(). How to get "out of office"?

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I use `EventsResource.ListRequest` to get Calendar event. It is request,But when I set "out of office" or "reminder" on Google Calendar,It do not request.

How can I solve this problem or Which parameter with `EventsResource.ListRequest` should I add?

This my code about `EventsResource.ListRequest`.

```
Public Function Fun_List(ByVal oService As CalendarService) As DataTable
    Dim oRequest As EventsResource.ListRequest = oService.Events.List("primary") 
    oRequest.TimeMin = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00.fffK")
    oRequest.ShowDeleted = False
    oRequest.SingleEvents = True
    oRequest.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime        

    Dim oEvent As Events = oRequest.Execute()      
    Dim dt_Calender As DataTable = Fun_CreatTable("Calendar")
        'BUILD DataTable
    Return dt_Calender
```

The "out of office" and "reminder" is like this image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U70qr.jpg)

Comment: What kind of reminder method you want to use?

Comment: @jess reminder just like I add a image in  issue